# APNs - Alert not displayed

Tags: iphone, alert, apple-push-notifications

I have the following problem, related to the Apple Push Notification service on iPhone: if the app is on background when the remote notification arrives, the alert is never displayed.

I know the notifications are reaching the device because: 1) a badge is shown or a sound is played if the payload contains any and 2) if the app is on foreground, the method `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` gets called with the proper value on `userInfo`.

I noticed that on the *Notifications* settings on the device, my app has only the options *Badges* and *Sounds*, while other apps have also an *Alerts* option. My guess is that somehow my app has the alerts disabled, but I don't know how to enable it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if **UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert** is registered  in your appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions OR didFinishLaunching method.

it should look like that:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | 
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

- UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge - enables the badge.
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound - enables the sound.
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert - enables the alert.

an other, less reasonable is that you might disabled the "alert" in the Notification center in your device preferences.